# Using self. in a class with Gensim TfIDF

Tags: python, class, gensim, tf-idf

I have a class `TfidfRecommendations` with several methods and inputs. Some of the inputs are the trained model objects of [Gensims TfIDF model](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html) (the function `train_tfidf` below):

```
import gensim
from gensim import models, corpora, similarities
def train_tfidf(data):
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(data)
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in data]
    tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
    index = similarities.SparseMatrixSimilarity(tfidf[corpus], num_features=len(dictionary))
    return tfidf_model, tfidf_dictionary, tfidf_index
```

Where `data` is a pandas dataframe of text documents (one document per row).

I use the output from `train_tfidf` above, as input into `TfidfRecommendations`:

```
class TfidfRecommendations:

    def __init__(self, data, tfidf_dictionary, tfidf_model, tfidf_index):
        self.data               = data
        self.tfidf_dictionary   = tfidf_dictionary
        self.tfidf_model        = tfidf_model
        self.tfidf_index        = tfidf_index

    ...

    def get_sims(self, query):
        # query is a list of strings to be compared to the corpus data
        vec_bow = self.tfidf_dictionary.doc2bow(query)
        sims = self.tfidf_index[self.tfidf_model[vec_bow]]
        return sims
```

the problem with the class `TfidfRecommendations` is that it returns a list of tuples for `sims` which is incorrect:

```
tfidf_model, tfidf_dictionary, tfidf_index = train_tfidf(data)
TFIDF = TfidfRecommendations(data, tfidf_dictionary, tfidf_model, tfidf_index)
sims = TFIDF.get_sims(query_text) # query_text is a list of string tokens
print(sims)
>>>[(4, 0.004360197614450217),
   (19, 0.044387503503385946),
   (46, 0.10344463256852278),
   (82, 0.01845695743910715),
   (125, 0.024611722270581393),
   (133, 0.045794061264144204)]
```

Whereas it should return a numpy array of length `len(data)` with each entry being a cosine similarity between `query_text` and each row in `data`. This works fine if `get_sims` is its own independent function outside of the class `TfidfRecommendations`

```
def get_sims(query, tfidf_dictionary, tfidf_index, tfidf_model):
    # query is a list of strings to be compared
    # to the corpus data
    vec_bow = tfidf_dictionary.doc2bow(query)
    sims = tfidf_index[tfidf_model[vec_bow]]
    return sims

get_sims(query, tfidf_dictionary, tfidf_index, tfidf_model)
>>> array([ 0.00123292,  0.0080641 ,  0.00420302, ...,  0.        ,
    0.0101376 ,  0.00987199], dtype=float32)
```

**What is going wrong here?** Why can't gensim model objects be used with `self.` inside a class? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did not read all yet, but did you initialize `self.tfidf_index = tfidf_model` on purpose?

Comment: @strippenzieher thanks for pointing that out. Edited the question - problem still stands